# Add a facebook share button

Tags: facebook, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to add a facebook share button to share a link in my facebook application.
I have the following code in my application:

```
<fb:share-button class="meta">
    <meta name="medium" content="mult"/>
    <meta name="title" content="my content"/>
    <meta name="description" content="some content"/>
    <link rel="image_src" href="url to image location" />
    <link rel="target_url" href="mylink"/>; 
</fb:share-button>
```

Comment: Maybe you can tell us which API you are using? PHP or JS.

Comment: and also add some info about your current code, and what is not working now

Comment: a dialogue box is opened and it remain processing :(

Comment: <fb:share-button class="meta">
<meta name="medium" content="mult"/>
<meta name="title" content="my content"/>
<meta name="description" content="some content"/>
<link rel="image_src" href="url to image location" />
<link rel="target_url" href="http://mylink"/>
</fb:share-button>
this code i have added my application..

Comment: @anupam, What is not working?

Comment: i place a facebook share button it appears on page when i click it a box is opened and it get infinite pocess no proper share box shown.........

Answer (score 0):

Did you add xml namespace for fbtags into your page?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: thanx for your response but i added xml namespaces even like button work properly but not share button .....wat to do...... :(

Comment: is the «share button» rendered? Can you see it on your page?

Comment: ya i can see share button on my page

Comment: and if it's rendered correctly, what happens when you click on it? Do you have any JS erorrs? Considering you are using Firefox, if you have FireBug plugin, do you see any calls to fb server after you clicking this button?

Comment: ya when m click it it seeems that it will open a share box but it will nt happend...

Comment: may be it help to answer that it look like a link not button is it normal........??

Comment: maybe, is it possible, you could put all this code to some separate page, make it accessible and add link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this code and it will start working.

Script:
stLight.options({publisher:'a6a03b49-3e57-4d13-97cc-d54044e09dc5'});

Button Code:

Change Link according to your project. First try it in new file.